# For (loop) dynamic creation

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, dynamic, for-loop

I'm trying to create dynamic balls by using a `for` loop.
For some reason I get two objects (trace show 2 balls and their DIFFERENT properties), but on the stage I can see just a last one created.

This is my code:

```
var randomBall_mc:ball=new ball();
for (i=1; i<3; i++)
{
        addChild(randomBall_mc);
    randomBall_mc.name="randomBall"+i;
    randomBall_mc.x=150*i;
    randomBall_mc.y=175;
    randomBall_mc.height=20*i;
    randomBall_mc.width=20*i;
        trace("randomBall"+i);
    trace(randomBall_mc.x);
    trace(randomBall_mc.height);
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**var randomBall_mc:ball=new ball();** should be inside the for loop in order to create more than ONE "ball"

```
for (i=1; i<3; i++) {
var randomBall_mc:ball=new ball();**
addChild(randomBall_mc);
randomBall_mc.name="randomBall"+i;
randomBall_mc.x=150*i; randomBall_mc.y=175;
randomBall_mc.height=20*i;
randomBall_mc.width=20*i; trace("randomBall"+i);
trace(randomBall_mc.x);
trace(randomBall_mc.height);}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're instantiating the ball only once before the loop instead of doing it for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is spot on, but polishing the code up a little:

`var ball:Ball;                  // Observe convention: capitalise class names
var i:int = 0;                  // Make sure to type your variables
for (; i < 3; i++) {
    ball = new Ball();
    ball.name = "randomBall"+i;
    ball.x = 150 * i;
    ball.y = 175;
    ball.height = 20 * i;
    ball.width = 20 * i;

    addChild(ball);             // Configure your instance first;
                                // then add it to the display list

    trace("ball:", i, ball.x, ball.height); 
}`